# Changing background colour of UIView cell component to green does not render component in green,

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

This question is about rendering components of a user interface in Objective-C.

I am trying to get a green stripe to be displayed down the right hand side of a table cell whenever the data in it is considered valid.

In order to achieve this, I decided to create a UIView object, called validatedBar as a component of a custom UITableViewController object in the position and the shape of a thin green bar aligned along the right hand side of the table cell. When the table cell is being rendered to the display, I check to see whether the validatedBar needs to have its background colour set to green as opposed to the regular white. The following extract hopefully shows the relevant information:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *scheduleItem = @"ScheduleItemTableCell";

    NSLog(@"cellForRowAtIndexPath");

    ScheduleItemTableCell *cell = (ScheduleItemTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:scheduleItem];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ScheduleItemTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    ScheduleListItem *item = [self.scheduleItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // Other detail being loaded has been removed for brevity.

    if(item.validated == YES){

        NSLog(@"Should set the validated bar for list item number %ld",(long)indexPath.row);
        cell.validatedBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

When the cell is rendered, a green bar does not appear where I think it should even though I see the output displayed in the log.

What am I not doing? Is there anything not clear in this question that I should provide, or is there a pretty obvious solution?

Comment: Can you also show us the code for how you are creating the `validateBar` in your Custom cell?

Comment: @GurtejSingh I'll endeavour to get something to you in a future post. In the meantime, I've noticed that when I change the simulator's orientation, a green rectangle appears. I've created a table cell as a .xib, and I thought I'd added the view object to be right aligned so that when one reoriented one's iPhone, it would always appear on the right hand side. Obviously I haven't?

Comment: what's your validatedBar? I think yours is an autolayout issue if it appears when you rotate

Comment: @GurtejSingh I do not know how to provide you an image in these forums, however, hopefully I can describe what I'm trying to do. I have a table with one column. The cells in the table are supposed to fill the screen left to right while maintaining a predefined height. I want to display a green bar in cells which are "valid", and none in those that are not. I want the green bar to appear on the right hand side of the cell in either portrait or landscape mode; hence, the width of the cells are going to change relative to this mode. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: Hmmm... I think my answer to this question might just have something to do with accessory views... hmmm...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is correct...

```
if (cell == nil)
{
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ScheduleItemTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

Without looking I don't think you can call LoadNibNamed at this point. It may work for you but it's definitely not by design and more by accident and thus, your view is not working properly and the background colour is not being changed as expected.

Try this approach...

```
NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ScheduleItemTableCell";
    ScheduleItemTableCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[ScheduleItemTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
```

Can you see the difference in how the two code snippets?
Change this and the rest of your code should work. Let me know??

Comment: Nothing is being rendered to the display with your suggestion. I believe this is because the caller to cellForRowAtIndexPath isn't actually adding items to the UITableView.

Comment: The problem appears to be that the green rectangle is being drawn, but is being drawn outside the display area of the iPhone because when I rotate the simulator view from portrate to landscape the bar appears and when I reorientate back, it disappears. Any suggestions to do with layout perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

I have the feeling your layout might be wrong. To verify position the bar at the left of the cell (always visible). If that works, then fix your layout. Maybe you set the wrong constraint(s). And please also take the advice of @latenitecoder!

Comment: I'm a bit stumped with layout. It appears that the green bar is being rendered correctly, but not within the display when the device is being used in portrait mode. How do I tell the device that the bar should be rendered close to the right hand side of the screen regardless of orientation?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you can't get it to change is because it has already been drawn during the drawRect stage of the view initialisation.  That is why when you change orientation and it re-draws itself, you see your colour changed.

To make an immediate change, you will have to re-draw the UIView after setting the colour, as follows:

```
[cell.validatedBar setNeedsDisplay]
```

Note that this will not necessarily happen immediately after, but it notifies the view to re-draw as soon as possible.  Apologies if the Obj-C code is wrong, I'm a Swiftie.

Comment: The bar appears to be being drawn, however it is not being rendered in portrait mode because the view coordinates are not within the physical hardware coordinates. I always want the view coordinates to be within the hardware coordinates so that the user will see this bar to the right of the single table cell within which the validated bar is being drawn. Any tips?

Comment: About Swif: I've got things I want to do with my life, and Apple decides that inventing a new language that replaces Objective-C (C by name only) would be a good thing. Enough of this zeitgeist thing that apple tries to push down my throat, I see what it really is!